# Java Replace double quote which is not in pair

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, double-quotes

I have a string like

```
"ABC def" xxy"u
```

I want to replace the double quote which is not in pair.

So in above example I want to replace only `xxy"u` double quote not first two which is in pair.

Output should be in this format.

```
"ABC def" xxy\"u
```

Should work with every non pair double quote - `"111" "222" "333" "4` so here `"` before 4 should be replaced with `\"`

Thanks in advance.

It would be great if it will detect the actual pair too, instead of last double quote.
EX: `"AAA" "bbb" "CCC "DDD"` -> should be replaced by `"AAA" "bbb" \"CCC "DDD"`

This is what I am using

```
    int totalCountOfDQ = countOccurence(s, '"');
    int lastIndexOfDQ = s.lastIndexOf('"');
    if(totalCountOfDQ % 2 == 1){
        String start = s.substring(0, lastIndexOfDQ);
        String end = s.substring(lastIndexOfDQ+1);
        s = start + "\\\"" + end;
    }
```

and it is working for my example
Thought it is not working `"4 "111" "222"` for correctly

Comment: Check the count of `"` and if its odd remove the last one.

Comment: Can you share what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanx @SubirKumarSao, I want the same. I am new to it, I am using java 1.6, I cant find any direct function for the string to count quotes.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao, That would fail for `"4 "111" "222"`.

Comment: your input values are alway seperated by " "? Then your Inputstring looks like [(")value(") ]+ ?

Comment: @Akshay Use a combination of regex and substring. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the next:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("\\B\"\\w*( \\w*)*\"\\B");

private static String replaceNotPairs(String input) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    int start = 0;
    int last = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        start = matcher.start();
        sb.append(input.substring(last, start).replace("\"", "\\\""));
        last = matcher.end();
        sb.append(matcher.group());
    }
    sb.append(input.substring(last).replace("\"", "\\\""));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("src: %s%nout: %s%n%n",
            "\"ABC def\" xxy\"u",
            replaceNotPairs("\"ABC def\" xxy\"u"));
    System.out.printf("src: %s%nout: %s%n%n",
            "\"111\" \"222\" \"333\" \"4",
            replaceNotPairs("\"111\" \"222\" \"333\" \"4"));
    System.out.printf("src: %s%nout: %s%n%n",
            "\"AAA\" \"bbb\" \"CCC \"DDD\"",
            replaceNotPairs("\"AAA\" \"bbb\" \"CCC \"DDD\""));
    System.out.printf("src: %s%nout: %s%n%n",
            "\"4 \"111\" \"222\"",
            replaceNotPairs("\"4 \"111\" \"222\""));
    System.out.printf("src: %s%nout: %s%n%n",
            "\"11\" \"2 \"333\"",
            replaceNotPairs("\"11\" \"2 \"333\""));
}
```

The output for the example input:

```
src: "ABC def" xxy"u
out: "ABC def" xxy\"u

src: "111" "222" "333" "4
out: "111" "222" "333" \"4

src: "AAA" "bbb" "CCC "DDD"
out: "AAA" "bbb" \"CCC "DDD"

src: "4 "111" "222"
out: \"4 "111" "222"

src: "11" "2 "333"
out: "11" \"2 "333"
```

See the explanation for the regex:

```
\B\"\w*( \w*)*\"\B
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

(from   http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex):

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \B                       the boundary between two word chars (\w)
                           or two non-word chars (\W)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \"                       '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \"                       '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \B                       the boundary between two word chars (\w)
                           or two non-word chars (\W)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this algorithm?

Count the number of double quotes.  If there is an even number, do nothing.  If there is an odd number, replace the last double quote with a `\"`

Comment: How would it handle `"4 "111" "222"`?

Comment: Can you share me a good algorithm, I can make it but I am afraid that I will make it too much fuzzy. Thanx

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I will give ideally (with respect to my question) "4 "111" "222\" but you would wonder it should do \"4 "111" "222" then that would be greate.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal If my algorithm doesn't handle that input correctly then I misunderstood the question.  What's OP asking for, then (i.e. a characterization of the output given an input)

Comment: Good call @RaviThapliyal +1

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a regex matching to check for this.

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("\".*\"");
Pattern myPattern1 = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)$");
var input=yourString;//assign your string to a new variable
input=input.replaceAll(myPattern,' match ');//replace all portions in " with your own string
if(input.matches("\"")) {
   yourString.replaceAll(myPattern1,/\\/);//if there is a dangling ", replace with a \ in your original string
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Aashray, but I am very much new to regexes, can you kindly explain?

Comment: I have included comments as to what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a loop following code should work:

```
String s = "\"111 \" \" 222\" \" 333\" \"4";
// s.replaceAll("[^\"]+", "").length() gives count of " in String
if (s.replaceAll("[^\"]+", "").length() % 2 == 1) {
    int i = s.lastIndexOf('"');
    s = s.substring(0, i) + "\\\"" + s.substring(i+1);
}
System.out.println(s); // "111 " " 222" " 333" \"4
```

Comment: This wont work for following case  "AAA" "bbb" "CCC "DDD" -> should be replaced by "AAA" "bbb" \"CCC "DDD"

Comment: @anubhava thanx, the solution will work for my case
P.S. this will work for my, but not for every case if double quote comes in between

Comment: @Prabhakaran: That's wrong. OP wants to replace only last unmatched double quote not the middle one.

Comment: @Akshay: Please elaborate what you mean by `if double quote comes in between`. An example: `"4 "111" "222"` can be considered as pairs: `1: "4 ", 2: " ", 3: 222"` hence `222"` is unbalanced.

Comment: My edited answer gives: `4 "111" \"222` for input of: `4 "111" "222`

Comment: @anubhava your answer does not work for `"11" "2 "333"` if I want answer `"11" \"2 "333"` but it will give `"11" "2 "333\"`

Comment: Yes that's right. How can you pinpoint that `"` before `2` is mismatched one. First string is `"11"` and 2nd can be: `"2 "` and final double quote after `333` is the mismatched one. How do you figure out `a double quote which is not in pair`, you need to define is clearly.